# OS X: Create user-groups, that are not shown in Systempreferences "Users & Groups" PrevPane

Tags: macos, command-line, user-accounts, osx-el-capitan, user-groups

I created some hidden Users on OS X, using `dscl . -create /Users/<usershortname> IsHidden 1`, that work as administraters.

For some reasons, I like to place the HOME-folders of different groups of these admins in different subfolders of /var and to give these groups rights for there groups top-folder.

My Problem is, that, if I create these groups via GUI / SystemPrefPane, they will be displayed there, so that StandartUsers can see these groups and have a starting-point for further examination.

I do allwas know, how to create groups via `dscl . create /Groups/<groupname>`. But how to hide these groups from the standart-dialogs in GUI? As there are some custom-groups, that are created from f.e. installed software, there must be a way to hidem them. I think this behavior will strongly depend upon the GroupID. So, there are two questions:

1. What is the correct keyword for creating the GroupID via the "dscl"-Method: "dscl . -create /Groups/groupname  5555"??
2. a) Is there a special range of GroupID, that is free for custum-use?
   b) Is there a special range of GroupIDs, that will not shown in the above mentionend GUI-Dialogs. 
   c) How to find already used GroupIDs in these ranges, to avoid conflicts?